# servlets behind a proxy: getting un-proxied URL

Tags: java, servlets, wicket, mod-proxy

Is there anything in the Servlet spec, Tomcat, or Wicket that will allow a webapp running behind mod_proxy to **determine the non-proxied URL of the request**?

We need to send out emails with links in them. I had been using the following bit of Wicket to construct URLs to specific pages in the app:

```
String relURL = RequestCycle.get().getRequest().getRelativePathPrefixToWicketHandler();
RequestUtils.toAbsolutePath(relURL);
```

Since the emails don't go back out through the proxy, of course the URLs don't get re-written, and end up looking like `http://localhost/...`.

Right now the best I can do is to hard-code the URLs to our production server, but that's setting us up for some debugging headaches when running on dev/test machines.

Using `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()` isn't really a solution, since that's likely to return `prod1.mydomain.com` or somesuch, rather than `mydomain.dom`, from which the request likely originated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As answered for the question [Retain original request URL on mod_proxy redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070335/retain-original-request-url-on-mod-proxy-redirect):

> If you're running Apache >= 2.0.31 then you might try to set the
>   ProxyPreserveHost directive as described [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost) .
>
> This should pass the original Host header trough mod_proxy into your
>   application, and normally the request URL will be rebuild there (in
>   your Servlet container) using the Host header, so the schema location
>   should be build using the host and path infos from "before" the proxy.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there anything in the Servlet spec, Tomcat, or Wicket that will allow a webapp running behind mod_proxy to determine the non-proxied URL of the request?

No.  If the reverse proxy doesn't put the information that you require into the message headers before passing them on, there's no way to recover it.

You need to look at the Apache Httpd documentation to figure out how to get the front-end to put the information that you need into the HTTP request headers on the way through.  (It can be done.  I just can't recall the details.)

Comment: Just for info: instructions on how to configure `mod_proxy` are available in [tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/proxy-howto.html) as well.