# getting URL to a webapp context (the base URL)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, servlets

Sometimes you need to construct a full URL to your web app context inside a servlet/JSP/whatever based on `HttpServletRequest`.
Something like **http://server.name:8080/context/**. Servlet API doesn't have a single method to achieve this.

The straightforward approach is to append all URL components to a `StringBuffer`, like

```
ctxUrl = sb.append(req.getScheme()).append("://")
.append(req.getgetServerName()).append(":")
.append(req.getServerPort()) etc
```

I wonder if there's anything wrong with this alternative (which is 10 times faster):

```
ctxUrl = req.getRequestURL();
ctxUrl = ctxUrl.substring(0, ctxUrl.lastIndexOf("/")));
```

Will two above methods *always* produce the same result?

Comment: If your URL contains a fragment part, in which slashes are valid, then  you have a problem

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's called the "base URL" (the one you could use in HTML `<base>` tag). You can obtain it as follows:

```
StringBuffer url = req.getRequestURL();
String uri = req.getRequestURI();
String ctx = req.getContextPath();
String base = url.substring(0, url.length() - uri.length() + ctx.length()) + "/";
```

Your `ctxUrl.substring(0, ctxUrl.lastIndexOf("/")));` approach will fail on URLs with multiple folders like `http://server.name:8080/context/folder1/folder2/folder3`.

#### See also:

- [How to use relative paths without including the context root name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764405/how-to-use-relative-paths-without-including-the-context-root-name) (for a JSP answer)
- [How get the base URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878275/how-get-the-base-url) (for a JSF answer)

Comment: the only issue is that StringBuffer's `substring` returns String which doesn't have `append` method

Comment: Fixed. Sorry, just typed from top of head and SO editor didn't perform compile checks.

Comment: and `+1` to substring's second argument rather than String concatenation could be a better idea, unless there is some other use case that I don't see :)

Answer (score 17):

The following will get the context URL and resolve things appropriately.

```
URI contextUrl = URI.create(req.getRequestURL().toString()).resolve(req.getContextPath());
```

This will do all the necessary processing for ports, slashes and what not.  It will also work for the root context as req.getContextPath() will return `""`

If you are using a proxy server you need to ensure that the original `Host:` request is passed in (e.g. [Apache ProxyPass instructions to `ProxyPreserveHost`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6101477/242042).

Comment: This one didn't work for me.  To be precise, it worked fine when my path was http://localhost:port/app-name/module/page, but it didn't work when I put it in beta and the path was https://subdomain.domain.com/module/page.  It left the module on in that case.  So use wisely, and if your distribution url structure is different then your development url structure, you may want to try something else.

Comment: It worked for me when I accessed the page from app server. But, when I accessed it from from webserver it generated app server url.

Comment: If you are using Apache as a proxy you should enable `ProxyPreserveHost` http://stackoverflow.com/a/6101477/242042

Answer (score 2):

Suppose,

We want to get *http://server.name:8080/context/* from anywhere in Java web app project.

```
String uri = request.getRequestURI();
//uri = "/context/someAction"
String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
// url = "http://server.name:8080/context/someAction"
String ctxPath = request.getContextPath();
// ctxPath = "/context";
url = url.replaceFirst(uri, "");
// url = "http://server.name:8080"
url = url + ctxPath;
//url = "http://server.name:8080/context"
```

using this code block, we can get the URL