# How can I get root-context url with JAX-RS?

Tags: jax-rs

With given Application

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication {
}
```

[UriInfo#getBaseUri](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getBaseUri--) gives me an application path.

```
@Context
private UriInfo uriInfo

uriInfo.getBaseUri(); // http://address/<context-path>/api
```

<s>How can I get context-path?</s>
How can I get full URL to context-path?

```
http://address/<context-path>
```

**UPDATE**

I currently using code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27072513/330457).

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

final URI contextUri
     = URI.create(servletRequest.getRequestURL().toString())
    .resolve(servletRequest.getContextPath());
```

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get application context, you can inject the ServletContext in your REST method and retrieve contextPath from it, for example like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Catalog find(@PathParam("id") Long id, @Context ServletContext servletContext) {
    String contextPath = servletContext.getContextPath();
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**

To get the "full URL to context-path" you want. You could also inject the HttpServletRequest with @Context annotation and use *getScheme()*, *getServerName()* and *getServerPort()* methods to build it.

Comment: Sorry I meant full URL to contextPath. Not just contextPath.

Answer (score 4):

One possible way is using `HttpServletRequest`.

```java
@Context
private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

final URI contextUri
     = URI.create(servletRequest.getRequestURL().toString())
    .resolve(servletRequest.getContextPath());
```